# How to avoid leaking type information when using Spring’s converters?

Tags: spring-mvc, security, exception

In a Spring MVC application, I registered a converter in `@InitBinder` to convert numeric query parameters to some domain type. It works fine. However, when the conversion fails, the resulting error object (using [zalando/problem-spring-web](https://github.com/zalando/problem-spring-web)) will leak details about the requested Java type to the client. This is considered a problem by our security experts.

The culprit it *probably* not the Problem-library creating the answer – it just takes the message from the exception that is thrown. This message is created in the constructor of `TypeMismatchException`. This is the exception that will be wrapped around any exception that I throw myself. I can throw it directly and pass a number of `null` values into it until the message becomes `Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String'`. This is half-good, because the target type is not encoded there.

Is there a way to pass a *meaningful* message out of the converter, yet avoid the target type appearing in the message of the exception that bubbles up?